# Facebook login doesn't works on iOS 10 Titanium SDK 5.3.1.GA and 5.5.0 Beta

Tags: facebook, appcelerator

I'm having an issue with a titanium app and login with Facebook. The login process with facebook works fine on iOS 9 but not in iOS 10 Beta.

The web view comes up, shows the app as already authorized, I tap OK the webview reloads but then nothing happens, it stays on a blank page.

Does anybody have a workaround for this?

I'm using the SDK 5.3.1.GA and the 5.5.0 Beta, but with both i have the same problem in iOS 10. The version of facebook module is 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

After several tests, the only way to solve the problem was to make a downgrade of facebook module version from 5.2.0 to 4.0.5 and works fine on iOS 9 and iOS 10 Beta and GM.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a bug on the current ti.facebook module. I'm having the exact same problem.

I have reported it on JIRA and you can track it there:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23890

I have tried to compile the latest ti.facebook module using the latest Facebook SDK available (4.15.1) that has Xcode 8/ iOS 10 compatibility changes but it didn't work and showed the same problem with a blank page on the webview.

Comment: The problem has been solved in the last SDK release: https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/09/ga-release-for-titanium-sdk-5-5-0-appcelerator-cli-5-5-0-appcelerator-studio-4-7-1/ Thanks @ygbr for the jira report